# DatePicker in asp.net mvc visual basic

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Helo, I'm working on a small Project with Visual Studio 2015, ASP.NET 5, MVC.
I need to know how to develop in visual basic to use a datepicker to enter dates using a calendar in the date fields.

Comment: Hi. Please add more details to your question, such as: what exactly is your goal, what specifically is your problem, code you have so far, what have you tried to resolve your issue. As it currently stands, this question is too broad and is not a good fit on StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should understand that you could use Jquery in your view.

Please refer to the MS document for example [Using the HTML5 and jQuery UI Datepicker Popup Calendar with ASP.NET MVC](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/using-the-html5-and-jquery-ui-datepicker-popup-calendar-with-aspnet-mvc/using-the-html5-and-jquery-ui-datepicker-popup-calendar-with-aspnet-mvc-part-4)